# Angular rooting front-end <-> back-end Cant root findByKey() in front end

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

So, i use postman to test if my findByKey() in back-end works and in fact it works. However, when i try it in front-end services i cant return an object. it returns me an observable everytime i console.log.

Sample 1:
Back-end root

```
public async findByKey() {
            this.app.get("/Path/Contains/:expression", (async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
                var pathListDTO = await this.service.findByKey(req);
              
                if (!pathListDTO) {
                    res.status(400).send("The path was not found!");
                } else {
                    res.json(pathListDTO);
                }
            }));
        }
```

Sample2:
Front-end root

```
 findByKey(key: string) {
return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/Contains/?key=${key}`);
```

}

I dont know if the problem is the contains but in back-end works in postman so idk

here is my baseUrl

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9001/path';
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're subscribing to your service correctly.
Try this :

```
this.frontendService.findByKey(yourKeyHere)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        // Here where you get your result
        console.log(result)
      },
      error => {
        // Here where you handle Errors
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Question solved

I just needed to change this

```
findByKey(key: string) {
```

return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/Contains/?key=${key}`);
}

to this

```
findByKey(key: string) {
```

return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/Contains/${key}`);
}